# Python: Import error when importing classes in same module (directory)

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-import

I am new to Python's module and package system. I currently have the following directory structure

ProjectDirectory:

```
Main.py
 
EntitiesDirectory/
       
        __init__.py
        Trip.py
        Plan.py
```

The init.py file is empty. The Plan.py contains a class definition for the class Plan.  The class Trip looks like this

```
 from  Plan import Plan
 Class Trip():
     def__init__(self,plan:"Plan"):
           do something with the plan object
```

When I run the Trip.py file inside from the Entities directory, there is no problem. However, when I try to import it n the Main.py file, I get the following error

```
from Entities.Trip import Trip
```

```
No module named Plan
```

I have  tried work the following changes inside Trip.py file

```
from .Plan import Plan
from Entities.Plan import Plan
from . import Plan
```

However nothing worked (relative directory error with no parent module). I am using Python 3.11 inside Anaconda.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Please note that imports _do not navigate directories_. Imports are only resolved by searching the Python path. `from .X` doesn't mean "in the same directory", it means "use the current package name as the base for the fully qualified dotted name of the package to import"